# NodeJS Sending a HTTPS SOAP Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap, https

I'm trying to send a SOAP request at a specific end point using nodejs.

My request looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:typ="http://company.com/nse/types">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <typ:Login>
         <!--You have a CHOICE of the next 2 items at this level-->
         <typ:Credential userName="x" password="y"/>
      </typ:Login>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I also have an **https endpoint** (e.g. https://hostname.com/box/) and a **WSDL** file.

Can someone please advise me of the best way to do this? I was looking through [milewise/node-soap](https://github.com/milewise/node-soap) and can't seem to find a spot to enter my required endpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the endpoint as part of the options:

```
var soap = require( 'soap' );
soap.createClient( ep.wsdl, { endpoint : ep.uri }, function( err, client ) {
   ...
});
```