# node-soap issue, invalid xml

Tags: node.js, meteor, soap-client, node-soap

I have spent hours figuring this issue out, but still haven't able to resolve this issue. If I send a request to the API with the same request body using Postman, it works just fine, but in the code it's giving me 'Invalid XML' error.

Anyone has any idea what am I doing wrong here?

**Code Snippet**

```
const host = "https://staging.familytreedna.com/ftdnawebservice/lifelinehometest.asmx?wsdl";

Soap.createClient(host, function(err, client){

    client.on('soapError', function(err, eid){
        console.log("REQUEST ERROR", err);
    });
    client.on('request', function(xml, eid){
        console.log("REQUEST SOAP", xml);
    });
    const _requestParam = {......};

    var result1 = client.LifelineHomeTestWS.LifelineHomeTestWSSoap.Create({
        message: _requestParam,
    });
});
```

**Request Body**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/">
    <soap:Body>
        <Create xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <message>
                <Authentication>
                    <UserName>USERNAME</UserName>
                    <Password>PASSWORD</Password>
                </Authentication>
                <Order>
                    <FtdnaOrderId>LH100031</FtdnaOrderId>
                    <RsOrderId>494648361009</RsOrderId>
                    <FirstName>Saud</FirstName>
                    <MiddleName></MiddleName>
                    <LastName>S.</LastName>
                    <FamilySurname>S.</FamilySurname>
                    <Address>abc </Address>
                    <City>Austin</City>
                    <State>TX</State>
                    <Zip>78704</Zip>
                    <Country>USA</Country>
                    <PhoneNumber>1341324123</PhoneNumber>
                    <CustomerEmail>mail@email.com</CustomerEmail>
                    <TotalPrice>79</TotalPrice>
                    <Gender>Male</Gender>
                    <Products>
                        <Product>
                            <Name>PRODUCT NAME</Name>
                        </Product>
                    </Products>
                    <Password>PASSWORD</Password>
                </Order>
                <Date>2018-05-21T19:16:31-04:00</Date>
            </message>
        </Create>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**Request Header**

[image]

**Response**

- faultcode: 500
- faultstring: 'Invalid XML'
- detail: 'Error: Unexpected close tag\nLine: 88\nColumn: 19\nChar: >
- statusCode: 500

[image]

Comment: Can you show your code that does the decoding?

Comment: decoding of the response?

Comment: You have shown the code that requests the data, but where you are using it

Comment: @Mikkel I just updated the code. `request` callback is where I'm getting this xml `Request Data` and after the `Create` method call, it goes straight to `soapError` callback.

Comment: You probably moved on since then - but I just ran into the same thing and it was caused by the fact that the WSDL had incorrectly specified the endpoint as http (instead of https), so the request was getting redirected and losing the post data

Comment: your node-soap request look like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16576348)
I solved the problem.

Comment: @NicolasGaller thanks, this was happening in my case.